# scikit learn. Custom Transformer set_params logic in GridSearchCV pipeline.

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I need to build my custom transformer, use it in pipeline and evaluate it tune parameters of that pipeline  using GridSearchCV.

I managed to implement simple custom transformers, following the advices from  [here](http://danielhnyk.cz/creating-your-own-estimator-scikit-learn/), but 
the questions occured while trying implement transformer with inner estimator and use this construction in GridSearchCV. I can not find the answer myself, as it seems to me, because I do not fully understand the subtleties of Search methods like (Grid/Randomized)SearchCV and set_params.

**"Introduction to ML with Python"** book describe  GridSearchCV logic rather naive:

```
...iterating over each parameters combination...
    init estimator
    fit estimator
    evaluate
```

But this naive approach can't answer to my question. To clarify my problem, lets' look at this case:

```
class OuterTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    _options = {'std':StandardScaler(),'mm':MinMaxScaler()}
    def __init__(self, option='std'):
        ...
```

The main question for me is *"where do I put the logic of choosing an internal estimator?"*. According to post  mentioned above, this should look something like this:

```
    def __init__(self, option='std'):
        self.option = option
    def fit(self, data, y=None):
        self.option = self._options[option] 
        ...
```

On the other hand, common sense dictates that GridSearch must pass parameters to initialize the internal estimator before calling **fit**, so the internal estimator should be selected in **__init__**.

It seems that first way works fine, but I just can not understand why. 
Can please somebody explain this phenomenon to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I understood the logic of initialization and re-initialization of parameters of estimators. This helped to answer my question:

The class fields must be initialized with those *original* values ​​that were passed to the constructor, rather than some *"derivatives"* from them, because for each re-initialization of the estimator, scikit calls **__init__**, passing parameters that were extracted from the instance by the method **get_params**  before CV start.

And the essence of **get_params** is that it scans the signature of the method **__init__** of the class and pulls from the instance of estimator fields with names corresponding to the names of the arguments of **__init__**(except *self* of course).

Thus, if we write *"derived"* values into fields inside **__init__** method, these *"derived"* values will be transferred to the next re-initialization, and that means everything will fail.

```
class OuterTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    _options = {'std':StandardScaler(),'mm':MinMaxScaler()}

    # good init- all fine
    def __init__(self, option='std'):
        self.option = option

    # bad init - will not work, because option is not an 'original' parameter.
    def __init__(self, option='std'):
        self.option = self._options[option]
```